# como puedo conseguir la lista de impresoras del cliente en ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net

alguien sabra si hay alguna forma de listar las impresoras del lado del cliente?
estaba usando system.drawing pero solo me lista las del servidor.

alguna sugerencia?

Comment: aqui tenes varias :https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/487135/Howplustoplusgetplusclientplussideplusprinterplusl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No se puede acceder a los recursos de un cliente de ASP.NET directamente por temas de seguridad. Necesitarás implementar un control `ActiveX` o usar `Silverlight` para ello. 
Te muestro un ejemplo de un control que implementé hace años. (algunos pasos pongo texto en inglés porque así tengo configurado mi `Visual Studio`.

1. Debes crear una libreria de clases y que firmar el ensamblado. `Project properties\Signing\Sign the assembly`.
2. Marcar `Project properties\Build\Output\Register for COM Interop`.
3. Establecer eventos de postcompilación (esto es para probar en tu local) en `Project properties\Build events\Post-build event command line` poner

   ```
     echo Un-register the components first
     "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\RegAsm.exe" "$(TargetDir)$(TargetFileName)" /tlb:ActiveXPrinter.tlb /codebase /u
     echo Register the components
     "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319 \RegAsm.exe" "$(TargetDir)$(TargetFileName)" /tlb:ActiveXPrinter.tlb /codebase
     echo All done
   ```
4. Ahora el código de tu control.

   ```
   using System;
   using System.Linq;
   using System.Management;
   using System.Reflection;
   using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
   using System.Text;
   using Microsoft.Win32;

   namespace ActiveXPrinter
   {
       [ProgId("ActiveXPrinter.PrinterHelper")]
       [ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.AutoDual)]
       [Guid("C0167B9D-2987-331A-97F6-3BCEF78E041A")]
       [ComVisible(true)]
       public class PrinterHelper
       {
           #region Register/Unregister

           [ComRegisterFunction()]
           public static void RegisterClass(string key)
           {
               // Strip off HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\ from the passed key as I don't need it
               StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(key);
               sb.Replace(@"HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\", "");

               // Open the CLSID\{guid} key for write access
               RegistryKey k = Registry.ClassesRoot.OpenSubKey(sb.ToString(), true);

               // And create the 'Control' key - this allows it to show up in 
               // the ActiveX control container 
               RegistryKey ctrl = k.CreateSubKey("Control");
               ctrl.Close();

               // Next create the CodeBase entry - needed if not string named and GACced.
               RegistryKey inprocServer32 = k.OpenSubKey("InprocServer32", true);
               inprocServer32.SetValue("CodeBase", Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase);
               inprocServer32.Close();

               // Finally close the main key
               k.Close();
           }

           [ComUnregisterFunction()]
           public static void UnregisterClass(string key)
           {
               StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(key);
               sb.Replace(@"HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\", "");

               // Open HKCR\CLSID\{guid} for write access
               RegistryKey k = Registry.ClassesRoot.OpenSubKey(sb.ToString(), true);

               // Delete the 'Control' key, but don't throw an exception if it does not exist
               k.DeleteSubKey("Control", false);

               // Next open up InprocServer32
               RegistryKey inprocServer32 = k.OpenSubKey("InprocServer32", true);

               // And delete the CodeBase key, again not throwing if missing 
               k.DeleteSubKey("CodeBase", false);

               // Finally close the main key 
               k.Close();
           }

           #endregion

           [ComVisible(true)]
           public string Devuelve(string mensaje)
           {
               //Método "dummy" que devuelve la entrada. Vale para probar que el ActiveX está bien instalado
               return mensaje;
           }

           [ComVisible(true)]
           public string GetPrinters()
           {
               //Obtenemos las impresoras instaladas en el cliente
               SelectQuery oSelectQuery = new SelectQuery { QueryString = "select * from win32_printer" };

               ManagementObjectSearcher search = new ManagementObjectSearcher(oSelectQuery);
               ManagementObjectCollection results = search.Get();

               //Guardamos el nombre de la impresora que actualmente tiene por defecto el usuario
               string impresoraOriginalPorDefecto = string.Empty;
               foreach (ManagementObject printer in results)
               {
                   impresoraOriginalPorDefecto += printer["Name"].ToString() + "|";
               }
               return impresoraOriginalPorDefecto;
           }

           [ComVisible(true)]
           public string GetDefaultPrinter()
           {
               string salida = string.Empty;
               //Obtenemos la impresora instaladas en el cliente que esté marcada como "por defecto"
               SelectQuery oSelectQuery = new SelectQuery { QueryString = "select * from win32_printer where Default = True" };

               ManagementObjectSearcher search = new ManagementObjectSearcher(oSelectQuery);
               ManagementObjectCollection results = search.Get();

               if (results.Count > 0)
               {
                   salida = results.OfType<ManagementObject>().First()["Name"].ToString();
               }

               return salida;
           }

           [ComVisible(true)]
           public Boolean SetDefaultPrinter(string printerName)
           {
               bool salida = false;

               //Obtenemos las impresoras instaladas en el cliente con el nombre especificado
               SelectQuery oSelectQuery = new SelectQuery { QueryString = "select * from win32_printer where Name = '"+ printerName + "'" };

               ManagementObjectSearcher search = new ManagementObjectSearcher(oSelectQuery);
               ManagementObjectCollection results = search.Get();


               if (results.Count > 0)
               {
                   results.OfType<ManagementObject>().First().InvokeMethod("SetDefaultPrinter", null);
                   salida = true;
               }

               return salida;
           }

           [ComVisible(true)]
           public Boolean SetDefaultPrinterMask(string printerMask)
           {
               bool salida = false;

               //Obtenemos las impresoras instaladas en el cliente
               SelectQuery oSelectQuery = new SelectQuery { QueryString = "select * from win32_printer" };

               ManagementObjectSearcher search = new ManagementObjectSearcher(oSelectQuery);
               ManagementObjectCollection results = search.Get();

               //Establecemos la impresora por defecto para imprimir
               foreach (ManagementObject printer in results)
               {
                   //Se encuentra la impresora con nombre que contenga lo que nos especifican y se pone por defecto
                   if (printer["Name"].ToString().ToUpper().Trim().Contains(printerMask.ToUpper()))
                   {
                       printer.InvokeMethod("SetDefaultPrinter", null);
                       salida = true;
                       break;
                   }
               }

               return salida;
           }
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: Gracias por tu contribución, pero responder preguntas que están realizadas sin seguir lo definido en [ask] provoca que el sitio tenga contenido de baja calidad, ayúdanos a orientar al OP a crear preguntas de buena calidad que sean útiles para toda la comunidad.

Comment: Hola. En qué no sigue lo definido en Cómo preguntar? El título por ejemplo para mi es muy claro. Y también entiendo que no hace falta código ya que está especificando en su pregunta que está usando ciertas clases y que no le funcionan.